# Is there any way to see cstat in P4V?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I just wonder if the UI (P4V) can provide the information from this command?

https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3458

Thanks for anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P4V used this feature at one point for a "workspace overview" tab that showed, among other things, what changelist you were synced to, but that no longer exists AFAIK.  You can, however, run `cstat` from a "custom tool" and see its output in the log pane.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I ended up running it in cmd and piped the results to file.
I tried to look but wanted to see if it was hidden in the menu somewhere.